# How to let external users upload files when compiling a form

Tags: form, guest-user, fileupload

we need to know if is it possible with Salesforce (we have an Enterprise Edition) to create a Form, accessible to not logged users, where we will ask some infos, and, through this form, let those users uploads some files required.

I'm searching this answer on the net and, till now, I don't really found an answer.
Someone has told me to use "Screen Flows Automation", but it seems to be blocked to logged users only. Others told me to use Chatter to do this, but on this point I really haven't find much infos.

Someone has some link, guide, idea, know-how to share with me?

Thanks all
A.

Answer (score 0):

- Follow these steps: [Let Community Guest Users Upload Files](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_networks_guest_upload.htm&release=218&type=5)
- Implement your custom file uploader LWC: [Lightning Web Component
  File Upload](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-file-upload/documentation)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for sharing with me those informations. I've successfully enabled the "Guest User Upload Files", but can't really find how to implement the custom file uploader LWC.
Is that a component for a Digital Experience Site? 'cause I can't find when creating a Digital Experience Site.

Thanks for your help!